# Neovim is looking for configs in current directory, how do I fix this?

Tags: neovim, error, startup

I am trying to configure neovim by adding plugins via lazy in my `C:\User\{username}\AppData\local\nvim` folder. However when I try to use neovim it only works in the nvim folder and no where else. I have checked the runtime path for neovim and I see the directory `C:\User\{username}\AppData\local\nvim` mentioned. I am also not specifying anywhere in my configuration to change where neovim looks for configs. Please help me out.

Here is the error:

```
    Error detected while processing C:\Users\kamal\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: C:\Users\kamal\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:1: module 'lua.init' not found:
        no field package.preload['lua.init']
        no file '.\lua\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\lua\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\lua\init\init.lua'
        no file '.\lua\init.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\init.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\loadall.dll'
        no file '.\lua.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        C:\Users\kamal\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:1: in main chunk
```

Here is the runtime var:

```
runtimepath=~\AppData\Local\nvim,~\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site,C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime,C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\pack\dist\opt\matchit,C:\Program Files\Neovim\lib\nvim,~\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\after,~\AppData\Local\nvim\after
```

I used the Neovim installer from the neovim github page (nvim-win64.msi).

My config files are located in `C:\Users\kamal\AppData\Local\nvim`.

What I meant by "it only works in the nvim folder" is that the configs that I have made are only used when I am in the config folder(`C:\Users\kamal\AppData\Local\nvim`). If I am in any other directory it launches the base version of nvim without my configs.

My neovim Config: https://github.com/kamal-hamza/neoivm_config.git

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/). Please [edit] to replace images of text with code-blocks of the relevant text.

Comment: sorry first question ever, i have updated with code blocks

Comment: I believe we would need more information about your installation. How did you installed Neovim (standalone, installer). Where is Neovim installed? What do you mean "it only work in the nvim folder" (When the current working directory is the Neovim installation directory)? What is the content of your `init.vim` or `init.lua` and where these files are on you disk? Sorry to ask so many question but in order to reproduce your problem I'm afraid we need more information  :-|

Comment: I used the Neovim installer from the neovim github page (nvim-win64.msi).

Comment: Neovim is installed in C:\Program Files\Neovim

Comment: My config files are located in C:\Users\kamal\AppData\Local\nvim

Comment: What I meant by "it only works in the nvim folder" is that the configs that I have made are only used when I am in the config folder(C:\Users\kamal\AppData\Local\nvim). If I am in any other directory it launches the base version of nvim without my configs.

Comment: BTW, you should [edit] all the additional information into your question. Comments are to ask clarifications, they may eventually be deleted. Better make the question contain all the information.

Comment: got it thanks. Added the additional info to the question

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. It is much more clear now. What we still miss is a simplifiés version of tour customization (`init.vim` or `init.lua` and their friands in the `lua` subfolder if any) that make it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. I have an `init.lua` file and I also have `init.lua` in my `lua` folder that has been connected using the `require` keyword.

Comment: Hello, it started working when I moved my `lazy.lua` into a folder named `config` and connected my `init.lua` to it.

Answer (score 1):

The error was that my `lazy.lua` was in my `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\nvim\lua` folder. However, you need to create a `config` folder inside your `lua` folder and put `lazy.lua` inside that `config` folder. Make sure you connect your `init.lua` to it by saying something like `require("config.lazy")`.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem :-) An alternative would have been to: `requier(lazy.lua)` but your solution is more 'standard'.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help btw

Comment: If your solution adress your need you can accept it 2 days after posting it. It allow the question to rest :-)